Is there a more efficient way of implementing wrap-around boundaries?
I seem to always have a similar situation in which I have a point that loops over to the opposite side when it crosses over a boundary. Is there a more efficient way of achieving the same result?
**win_dim: a tuple that contains the boundaries dimensions, (w,h) **
if self.pos[0] > win_dim[0]:
    self.pos[0] = 0
elif self.pos[0] < 0:
    self.pos[0] = win_dim[0]
if self.pos[1] > win_dim[1]:
    self.pos[1] = 0
elif self.pos[1] < 0:
    self.pos[1] = win_dim[1]

I've tried different ways to optimize, but I'm not very experienced so it has been a struggle.

Is this truly "wrap around", or just limiting? E.g. If the position is 5, but the dimension is 3, should the position be set as 0 or 2?

If you want actual wrap around behavior like @OneCricketeer is saying, that's typically implemented with the modulo operator: self.pos[0] %= win_dim[0]. Of course this would not be equivalent to your current code.

there isn't really anything inefficient about a couple pairs of if statements and assignments
